# How to properly include header files on OS X when XCode is installed in alternative director?

Tags: xcode, sdk, build-process

I have some projects that are failing to build because the header inclusion does not.

This is caused by the usage of `$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Headers/FlatCarbon`, but on my system Xcode was installed in another directory.

I also tried `SDK_DIR` without success and I was not able to locate information about these on Apple documentation.

How can I properly configure the project in order to be build independent of Xcode location?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct answer to your question, but a quick solution would be to make a symbolic link from /Developer to your XCode installation directory.

Comment: No way, I want a proper solution, one that would not require any manual operation.

Answer (score 0):

I got the proper answer from Apple forums, use `$(SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR)`.

Comment: Is this variable set as bash environment variable. I would have to use it from ANT build script. I have same problem as you , the build is looking for "/Developer/Headers/FlatCarbon" but XCode is elsewhere...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use this script with each new version of XCode to establish links to older SDKs. It relies on a copy of XCode 4.2 that I keep on a separate volume, but all it really needs is the SDKs folders. To add PPC support requires some extra work and XCode 3, but there are other good answers covering that subject.

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# Add older SDKs to the latest XCode
# TODO: Add older architecture, PPC
#

#### CHANGE THESE TO YOUR OWN PATHS ####
XCODE=/Applications/Xcode.app
XPLAT=$XCODE/Contents/Developer/Platforms
SRCDEV=/Volumes/Dev/Developer
SRCIOS=$SRCDEV/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs

#
# Add 10.6 and 10.7 support
#
cd $XPLAT/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
sudo ln -s $SRCDEV/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk MacOSX10.6.sdk
sudo ln -s $SRCDEV/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk MacOSX10.7.sdk

#
# Add iOS 5.0 and 6.1 support
#
cd $XPLAT/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
sudo ln -s $SRCIOS/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk iPhoneOS5.0.sdk
sudo ln -s $SRCIOS/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk iPhoneOS6.1.sdk

#
# Add 10.5 and PPC support
#

#  --- not currently implemented ---
```